# Schengen visa - employed while applying, unemployed while travelling

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, india, schengen-visas

I am a 25 year old Indian male currently employed in India, but I'll be quitting my job in a couple weeks. I wish to travel to the Schengen area next month for a vacation before I go to the US for education (I have an F1 visa). This would be my first time travelling to the Schengen area.

What should I fill in as the employment status in the visa application? I am technically currently working, but I can't arrange an NOC from the company since I am in the notice period and the vacation dates are beyond when I am employed with them. Should I just say I am not working right now?

This risks a rejection because I can neither claim to be a student (I am starting a month after the planned vacation) nor claim to have retired. My age further exacerbates the problem due to immigration risks.

I can show close ties to home financially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This constilation should pose no problem.

- your employment ends because you are starting an education in the US, both of which you can prove

If you can show that this just is a stopover (ticket to US with F1 Visa) and can finance the time in the Schengen area, this should be treated as a valid travel reason. It is basically an extended transit.

Write a short cover letter explaining the situation and send it in with the application.